# How to determine the distance between two matrices under the meaning of a matrix function?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory, norms, np

Suppose a nonlinear infinitely continous differentiable function $f:\mathbb{D}\mapsto \mathbb{R^+}$, where $\mathbb{D}\subset\left\{X|\text{rank}{X}=2,X\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}\right\}$ is a continous, open, convex set,

How to define a matrix norm $\left\|\cdot\right\|_p$ in $\mathbb{D}$, such that $\forall x_1, x_2\in \mathbb{D}$:
$$\lim\limits_{\left\|x_1-x_2\right\|_p\to 0}|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|=0,$$ $$\lim\limits_{\left\|x_1-x_2\right\|_p\to 0}\left\|x_1-x_2\right\|_2=0$$ $$\quad\lim\limits_{\left\|x_1-x_2\right\|_p\to 0}\left\|x_1-x_2\right\|_{\infty}=0,$$ $$\lim\limits_{\left\|x_1-x_2\right\|_p\to 0}\left\|x_1-x_2\right\|_1=0,$$

and the $9\times 1$ vectors $y_1 = x_1(:),y_2=x_2(:)$(use Matlab/Octave operator here)
$$\lim\limits_{\left\|x_1-x_2\right\|_p\to 0}\left\|y_1-y_2\right\|_2=0,$$

Must the calculation of such matrix norm be `NP`-hard?

Comment: I must be missing something here... why doesn't one of the usual [matrix norms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) work?

Comment: What's a *continuous set*?

Comment: by `continuous`, I mean `connected`

Comment: Usual matrix norm does not work because of the first criterion: $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|$ which is the most critical

Comment: To talk of continuity and differentiability, you have explain what you mean if you don't mean the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^9$. If you do, then all norms are equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>(This isn't an answer, but I'm not allowed to comment yet and I think this is a worthwhile question, even if it means violating the rules; i'll delete the post when the time comes)</strike>

You claim that usual matrix norms do not work because of the $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|$ criterion, but if $f$ is differentiable, then given any $x_1$ it is Lipschitz in some neighborhood of $x_1$ (with a constant that may depend on $x_1$), and hence $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\leq C \|x_1(:)-x_2(:)\|_1$. Did I miss something?

Comment: My puzzle mainly lies in the conflicts between `theoretical proof` and `numerical experiments`. Probably because the difference between $x_1$ and $x_2$ has not been small enough?

Comment: Do you mean that you did numerical experiments with some norm and the difference didn't seem to go to zero? Assuming you didn't have any bugs, it could be that a) the "norm" you used was degenerate, i.e. wasn't actually a norm, and could be $0$ even when $x_1\neq x_2$, or b) the function you were using was not sufficiently well-behaved to yield stable results at numerical precision. Perhaps you could edit your question with more details about what you were trying out?

Comment: I will need time to make it clear whether I made any mistake. Thank you for suggestions.